# Pairing array elements in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

Let's say i have an array called `teams`.
I want to plan `matches` for every `team` with every other `team`.

This is almost what i want except that same `matches` are added twice:

```
teams.each do |red_team|
  teams.each do |blue_team|
    if red_team != blue_team
      @planned_matches << Match.new(red_team, blue_team)
    end
  end
end
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check if it works

```
for i in 0..teams.length-1
  if i != teams.last
    for j in (i+1)..teams.length-1
      @planned_matches << Match.new(teams[i], teams[j])
    end
  end
end
```

EXAMPLE

```
teams = ['GERMANY', 'NETHERLAND', 'PARAGUAY', 'ARGENTINA']
for i in 0..teams.length-1
  if i != teams.last
    for j in (i+1)..teams.length-1
      puts " #{teams[i]}  Vs  #{teams[j]}"
    end
  end
end
```

O/P

```
 GERMANY  Vs  NETHERLAND
 GERMANY  Vs  PARAGUAY
 GERMANY  Vs  ARGENTINA
 NETHERLAND  Vs  PARAGUAY
 NETHERLAND  Vs  ARGENTINA
 PARAGUAY  Vs  ARGENTINA
```

Comment: The if statement doesn't do anything, i is an int and you are comparing it to a team name that is a String. But yeah, other than that, this is the best solution.

Comment: @Joshua :- oohhhhhhhhh yes i think it should be teams[i] != teams.last. I think it will work w/o if condition then. nocheck though.

Comment: You may want to use `upto` or `...` or `each_index`. Also, `for` isn't idiosyncratic ruby.

Answer (score 8):

In Ruby 1.8.7+ you can use [Array#combination](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Array.html#M000339):

```
teams = %w(A B C D)
matches = teams.combination(2).to_a
```

In 1.8.6, you can use [Facets](http://facets.rubyforge.org/) to do the same:

```
require 'facets/array/combination'
# Same code as above.
```

Comment: If only i knew how to install ruby 1.8.7+ on my fedora13 :)

Answer (score 0):

In your class Match, assuming internal attributes are `red` and `blue`

```
class Match
#...
  def ==(anOther)
    red == anOther.blue and anOther.red == blue
  end
#...
end
```

and the loop :

```
teams.each do |red_team|
  teams.each do |blue_team|
    if red_team != blue_team
      new_match = Match.new(red_team, blue_team)
      planned_matches << new_match if !planned_matches.include?(new_match)
    end
  end
end
```

*Explanation :*

The `include?` function of `Array` uses the `==` methods, so you just have to override it and giving it the behaviour you want for your Matches.

Comment: This looks a bit better to me than solution by Salil. :)

Comment: @Arnis L :- performance wise it will iterate 16 times for array of length 4 where mine is iterate for just 7 times.

Comment: But real issue with this one is - i lose equality in case match.red == another.red && match.blue==another.blue.

Comment: This kind of iterating doesn't conform well to the Ruby way, but nonetheless, Salil's answer is a many many times more efficient. Also, the implementation of == in this answer is very questionable. For example, with that definition, an instance of Match is not equal to itself.

Comment: @Arnis iterating over collections rather than accessing them by index.